# Hive dynamic partition by unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, partitioning

I am creating a table in Hive, running a mapper transformation and then saving a table. I want to partition the table based on when I ran the Hive query.

I create the table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable (
    test_test STRING
) PARTITIONED BY (time STRING)
LOCATION 'loc/table'
;
```

Then run the transformation and save the table while trying this:

```
FROM (
MAP 
one.test_test
USING 
'python job.py' 
AS test1
FROM 
one
) test_step
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE testtable PARTITION (time=unix_timestamp())
SELECT CAST ( test_step.test1 AS STRING ) AS test_test
;
```

However, when I do the

> time=unix_timestamp()

, I get an exception. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you hope to gain by this form of partitioning?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should work if you use dynamic partitioning (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-DynamicPartitionInserts). The partition field is just another column in the table, so if you have a value for the column in your query, then Hive will automatically put it in the right partition. So your statement would look something like this

```
FROM (
MAP 
one.test_test
USING 
'python job.py' 
AS test1
FROM 
one
) test_step
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE testtable PARTITION (time)
SELECT CAST ( test_step.test1 AS STRING ) AS test_test,
unix_timestamp() as time
;
```

Doing it like this might create a lot of partitions though, as the value of unix_timestamp() will change during execution of the query. It would be better to use an extra statement to create the partition first and then insert.

EDIT: To add a partition beforehand you'd need to set the timestamp you want somehow, e.g. a parameter for the script. Then

```
ALTER TABLE testtable ADD PARTITION (time=your_timestamp_here);
```

This would go before your original query where you replace unix_timestamp() with your_timestamp_here (which of course would be a valid unix timestamp).

Comment: Will the timestamp be the same for all entries of the row when I start off the transform query? What is the other way you stated? How would I create just one partition and add all items to that?

Comment: I think unix_timestamp() will be called for each row, but I'm not 100% certain about that, you might want to try it with a `limit 1000` and then use `show partitions` to see what it created.

Comment: The `add partition` might not even be needed if you set a timestamp manually, e.g. `123456 as time`.

Comment: What would be the best way to have a singular timestamp for all the rows that would be generated automatically and not manually by me?

Comment: Depends how you run your Hive script. You could set a Hive variable in advance and use that. If you run the script via Oozie you could produce the timestamp there and pass it as variable.